# How does Windows go from Sleep Mode to Hibernate?

Tags: windows-10, sleep, hibernate

I know in Windows 10 Power options, there is a setting that lets you control when to go into Hibernate from Sleep mode, but how does this actually work? How does Windows know when the laptop is already "sleeping" to switch it to Hibernate mode (or write the contents of memory to disk)? And does that involve actually waking up temporarily?

Comment: It will probably just prepare for Hibernation but instead of turning entirely off it will stay in sleep. You're probably talking about hybrid sleep. See [this blog post on Microsoft devblogs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110510-00/?p=10703).

Comment: _How does Windows know when the laptop is already "sleeping"_ - I don't understand which part you understand here. It has to enter sleep, right? If it started sleeping and wasn't woken up, then it's sleeping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most PCs have a hardware clock (RTC) which keeps time when the CPU is powered off. The RTC has also a ["scheduled wakeup"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock_alarm) function; the OS can [program](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/rtcwake.8.html) it to wake the system after a specified amount of time.

So whenever you suspend the laptop, immediately before entering the sleep state Windows programs the RTC to wake it up after exactly X hours or so. When the system is woken up (it's always a full wakeup), Windows checks which device it was woken by (using ACPI); possibly also whether the current time is exactly X hours since it was suspended.

If Windows sees that it was woken by its own scheduled RTC event (and not by lid/keyboard) it immediately goes back to sleep – this time in hibernate mode.

(In laptops, the firmware can also wake the system whenever battery is critically low; again the OS can recognize how/why it was woken up and automatically enter hibernation mode based on that.)

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Followup question - So when you say that the system is woken up (full wakeup) by RTC, then what I can actually see the screen light up? (if I program it so that sleep mode is activated when the lid is open say by the power button)

Comment: If it was a "time to hibernate" wakeup, then the OS just keeps the _video output_ disabled, so the display won't (well, shouldn't) light up.